# RadioButtons in JDialog in Swing?

Tags: java, swing

I need to display a dialog box which contains radio buttons; and when I select the appropriate radio button, the dialog box should disappear?

Comment: Causing a dialog to disappear when a user clicks a radio button in unintuitive.  Instead it would make more sense to present a dialog containing radio buttons along with OK and Cancel buttons to dismiss the dialog.

Comment: For some reason many people call it "swings". Stop doing that. It is called SWING! :)

Comment: Copyedited; please revert if incorrect.

Comment: What if the user selects the radio button by keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the others that having a "dialog disappear" on radio button click is not a very good UI design. Users generally expect that a "dialog disappears" when they select a button at the bottom (e.g. OK, Cancel, Yes, No, etc.).

In any event, if I am to assume that by "dialog disappears" you mean the window closes, then the way to do that is to call `dispose` on the dialog.

Also, you may want to consider using `JOptionPane`.

Answer (score 5):

**Try to use [TaskDialog](http://code.google.com/p/oxbow/) framework.** It helps to accomplish just the things you ask for in few lines of code. For your case using Command Links is the best solution.

[image]

Radio buttons are possible but not a better solution from usability point of view.

[image]

Comment: +1 Considering the requirement "must close on click" this offers the most intuitive solution.

Answer (score 2):

In your radio button listener, use `setVisible(false)`, as discussed in the articles [*How to Use Radio Buttons*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#radiobutton) and [*Creating and Showing Simple Dialogs*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#create).

Comment: Please edit your question to include your http://sscce.org/ that shows the problem. Also consider @Adamski's suggestion.